# Update Neo4J to the latest version

Tags: neo4j

0.1 on my Linux server and on my local Mac and want to update it to the latest version. Can I just download the latest pack and copy the graph.db files along with te plugins into the new version (after DB integrity check) to make the update work or is there anything else to be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade procedures are extensively documented, so RTM at http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/deployment-upgrading.html